# Netstat command to find a particular connection

Tags: command-line, server

When we find connection with `netstat` command is it possible to find a particular user? If so then how if someone chat with you on Facebook can we find their IP in Ubuntu?

Comment: cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39255764/2461638

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netstat will show you the current active connections on your own system.  This would show you, for example, your connection to facebook.  But your connection isn't with the person on facebook, it's with facebook.  You wont see their connection information if you go looking, just that with facebook.

Comment: how can find connection to user like i am chating with you here can i find your location and IP

Comment: My connection is between me and askubuntu.  Yours is between you and askubuntu.  There is no data shared between our connections that would provide either of us with the IP of the other.

Comment: right if we write some code which request server to give ip address of person to whom my data packages are received. Is it possible?

Comment: The web site generally takes action to prevent such a thing.  The browser they are using also plays a part (preventing xss, for example) so it's generally not feasible.  The best you could do is potentially provide a link to a server you control where you could then retrieve the ip address, but this has nothing to do with ubuntu at this point...

Comment: can you recommend me some good books for UBUNTU as a beginner